# Delete "duplicate rows" in pandas where with an additional condition

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

With the help of Jezrael i could edit my python script:

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("files")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

# combine all files in the folder
dfs_to_concat = []
for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";")
    df['file_identifier'] = [f] * len(df.index)
    dfs_to_concat.append(df)
combined_csv = pd.concat(dfs_to_concat)

# remove duplicates
m1 = combined_csv.duplicated()
m2 = combined_csv.duplicated(subset=combined_csv.columns[:-1])

combined_csv_final = combined_csv[m1 | ~m2]

# export to csv
combined_csv_final.to_csv("combined_csv_final.csv", index=False, sep=";", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

What this script is supposed to do is:

remove all duplicate rows ONLY where the "file_identifier" is distinct. DO NOT remove duplicates where "file_identifier" is the same.

However, it's not working. It does not remove the duplicate rows with distinct file identifiers. In fact, it does not remove any duplicate rows.

Does anyone know where it goes wrong? Apparently in Jezraels sample, it's working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine testing dupes per ech file in `m1` with testing dupes without last column with `|` for `bitwise OR` with `~` for invert mask:

```
m1 = combined_csv.duplicated()
m2 = combined_csv.duplicated(subset=combined_csv.columns[:-1])

df = df[m1 | ~m2]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[4,5,4,5,4,6],
         'b':[7,8,7,4,7,8],
         'file_identifier':list('aaabbb')
})
print (df)
   a  b file_identifier
0  4  7               a
1  5  8               a
2  4  7               a
3  5  4               b
4  4  7               b <- dupe with different filename
5  6  8               b

m1 = df.duplicated()
#print (m1)

m2 = df.duplicated(subset=df.columns[:-1])
#print (m2)

df = df[m1 | ~m2]
print (df)
   a  b file_identifier
0  4  7               a
1  5  8               a
2  4  7               a
3  5  4               b
5  6  8               b
```

Comment: hello @jezrael. Thank you very much. I just tried it, but for some reason, it does not remove the duplicates as it does in your example. I've inserted your suggestion right  before the "#export to csv" comment. is that the correct way?

Comment: @Zest - I think yes, also do you removed `combined_csv.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)` ?

Comment: yes, i basically changed my previous line with your suggested code.

Comment: @Zest - Maybe my problem is not understand how need remove dupes. E.g. if added new row to my sample data with `4,4,'c'`, so dupe only in `b` filename do you need remove it? It means removed row with index 4 ?

Comment: nono, you have understood it the right way. your sample does exactly what i want. 
i want to remove only duplicates, if they have different file_identifiers. but for some reason, when i try it with my csv, the duplicate with different file_identifiers are still there in the combined_csv-file.

Comment: hello @jezrael. Do you happen to know why it's not working with .csv files?

Comment: i just updated my code sample. maybe you can take a look?

Comment: @Zest - Without data is not easy test. Data are confidental?

Comment: Hi Jazrael, it used to be confidental but i also tested it with simple values like in your example. Did you manage to test it with 2 or 3 .csv files? I updated the code i am using in my question.

Comment: @Zest - Is possible send me 3 files with expected output to my email from my profile?

Comment: @Zest - I think sample data files, not real confidental

Comment: @Jezreal i will happily do so. thank you very much my friend!

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'. cant get it fixed

Comment: @Zest - Do you run code in IDE where is installed pandas?

Comment: yes, i guess. i dont know. its quite a hastle for 2 days already

Comment: my csv files have basically the same values as your sample. but for some reason, it does not work. all the duplicates stay